# VBA to FillDown Formula with changing cell reference

Tags: vba, excel, autofill, sumifs

I have a Sumifs function to be done in macro with 2 criterias. my  excel file is quite big. So my code looks like this :

```
Sub SumIfs()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("L2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.SUMifs(Range("G:G"),Range("A:A"),"Pen",Range("F:F"),"John")
End Sub
```

But i would like to change the "Pen" to its cell reference, which means "A2" and " John" remains constant for all the cells down in the F:F range. And the to fill the formula down for all the cells below. I used this code,

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.SUMifs(Range("G:G"),Range("A:A"), A2,Range("F:F"),"John")
```

But it only shows the value for A2 down in the cells when I did the filldown function. Please Help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You're not putting a formula in the cell, just a value.  You need to use an actual formula if you want to fill it down.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks for the reply, i have tried to use 
Sub Sumifsfunction()




With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Range("L2:L100").Formula = "=SUMifs(G:G,A:A,E2,F:F,"John")"
End With
End Sub
 but getting expected: end of statement error

Comment: You haven't doubled your double-quotation marks within that string.  (And you have a `With` block, but not using it for anything.)  You could have used `.Range("L2:L100").Formula = "=SUMifs(G:G,A:A,A2,F:F,""John"")"`

Comment: @YowE3K , Yes that was the problem with my codes, ur code helped me to figure it out, thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are after something like:

```
Sub SumIfs()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("L2:L" & .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
                    "=SUMIFS(G:G,A:A,A2,F:F,""John"")"
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want the **value**, rather than the **formula**, inserted into column L, you could extend that code to:

```
Sub SumIfs()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        'Assume we want to create values for every cell in column L down until
        'we get to the last cell in column G
        LastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Paste the formula
        .Range("L2:L" & LastRow).Formula = _
                    "=SUMIFS(G:G,A:A,A2,F:F,""John"")"
        'Convert to values
        .Range("L2:L" & LastRow).Value = _
                   .Range("L2:L" & LastRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the first code u provided worked exactly like what i want, thanks a lot  :)